# Dropdown not populating from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a dropdown list with PHP from a MySQL database. Right now nothing is populating in my dropdown. I have made sure I have the correct database name, server name, username, and password.

Here is my PHP file queryfunction.php:

```
<?php
function connect(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "******";
    $database = "lab4";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    mysqli_select_db($database);
}

function close(){
    mysqli_close();
}

function query(){
    $mydata = mysqli_query("Select * from country");
    while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($mydata)){
        echo '<option value = "' . $record['CountryAbbreviation'] . '">' .$record['CountryAbbreviation'] . '"</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is is my PHP file where I call this:

```
<?php
include_once "queryfunction.php";
connect();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html/>

<html>
```

Further down in the doc within a table:

```
<tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <td>
        <select name="CountryDropDown">
        <?php query() ?>
        </select>
        <?php close()?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have at least 2 issues - (1) a variable scope issue, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php as `$conn` is defined in `connect()`, but is not available outside that function. (2) you have `$mydata = mysqli_query("Select * from country");` but `mysqli_query()` requires the connection as the 1st param - `$mydata = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * from country");`, but the 1st issue needs to be addressed before this can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with change this line `while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($mydata)){` to this `while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($mydata,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){`
or show us your `$record` variable data

Comment: ok I have tried what both of you guys have suggested and still no luck. What do you mean show your $record variable data?

Comment: I don't know how to do what you are asking to do. But I have noticed that it doesn't matter what I call my database. So it seems like my query isn't going to to the right database. I tried adding the database name at the end of new mysqli and it seemed not display the rest of my html.

Comment: <?php query() ?> semicolan is also miss   <?php query() ; ?>